# Anyone knows of a 35x20x20cm cabin hand bag that's foldable?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, hand-luggage

The idea is to be able to fold it and put it inside the cabin bag that is 55x40x20 after the flight. Anyone knows any model like that?

Comment: Likely superflues, remember to get a bag with a zipper. I have used open topped bags but it is not easy to keep everything in when it is in the overhead locker or even under the seat in front of you.

Comment: Yes, for example I know several models like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A zippered nylon tote bag (sometimes sold as a "travel tote" or "shopping tote" or "tote in a pouch") is what I usually use in such situations. They can fold up quite small and light when empty, but can hold a lot unfolded. If I do wind up checking a bag, I'll always carry one with an emergency change of clothes, toiletries, and other supplies for the flight, and in case my luggage gets lost. They're also great for bringing souvenirs home.

It's hard to recommend specific models since I don't know where in the world you are, but a search on "zippered nylon tote" or "nylon travel tote" will get you in the right direction.

Baggu makes a few models, such as their [Cloud Tote](https://baggu.com/collections/nylon-pouches/products/3d-zip-set-black?variant=30977214471) (taller than your dimensions allow, but soft-sided, so it depends how much you fill it) and [these pouches](https://baggu.com/collections/nylon-pouches/products/3d-zip-set-black?variant=30977214471) (which do not have a shoulder strap). Eagle Creek makes a [Packable Tote](http://shop.eaglecreek.com/packable-tote/d/1400) that folds into itself (also larger, but soft) and Arc'teryx makes the [Index 10](https://www.zappos.com/p/arcteryx-index-10-boxcar/product/8326092/color/592284?zlfid=191&ref=pd_detail_1_sims_p_ab), [Index 5](https://www.zappos.com/p/arcteryx-index-5-boxcar/product/8326093/color/592284?zlfid=191&ref=pd_detail_1_sims_p_ab), and [Index 5+5](https://www.zappos.com/p/arcteryx-index-5-5-carbon-copy/product/8443934/color/463793). [A search on REI's website](https://www.rei.com/search.html?q=tote&origin=web&ir=q%3Atote&page=1) finds other good options, and [Cool Hunting did a feature on these bags](http://www.coolhunting.com/travel/packable-bags) (which they profit from).

[The Oxford Stowaway bag](https://cabinmax.com/stowaway/187-oxford-stowaway-0702679484630.html) is exactly 20x35x20cm ("ideal for the Ryanair second bag allowance"), though since it's made of canvas, it won't pack quite as flat as a light nylon bag.

Comment: At least you helped me with a name to search: "Packable Tote"! I think that's what I'm looking for: a "Packable Tote" with 35x20x20 dimension (I want to avoid any kind of trouble with low budget airlines). But that OXFORD STOWAWAY is really nice as well, good find!

Comment: amazon.co.uk is available to me, I have some friends there. Really nice. :) https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cabin-Max-Oxford-50x40x20cm-Luggage/dp/B00THC2OMY/?th=1 and https://www.amazon.co.uk/Oxford-Stowaway-Bag-20x35x20cm-allowance/dp/B015WKETLI/

Comment: The stowaway is not foldable, but I can use it in front of me so it's a nice approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime I use the sport bags. If it is not completely full with hard stuffs, you can compress in any direction, so nobody will really care about the dimensions. It seems that airlines like them (instead of hard cases), because they are more flexible on where to store them, and they could ev. put purse and jackets above it.

Just that the compression could have negative effects on toothpaste and shampoo. Pack fragile stuffs appropriately (with more care than in hard case).